# Concatenate two datetimes into a string date range

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas, concatenation

I have a pandas dataframe.

```
Data = pd.DataFrame([[datetime.datetime(2014,1,1),datetime.datetime(2014,1,3)]],columns=['date1','date2')
```

That dataframe has two datetime columns date1 and date2.

I want to create a new column that contains a string in the format below:

```
'1/1/2014 - 1/3/2014'
```

Right now I have this setup to create the new column, **but it keeps the trailing hms**:

```
Data['range'] = Data.apply(lambda x:'%s - %s' % (x['date1'],x['date2']),axis=1)
```

Finding it hard to strip just the date out since I am working with two columns rather than two values.  Any pointers?

Comment: Example of your data would be useful. And what do you meen by "Finding it hard"? you get any errors, or incorrect results? any examples would be useful.

Comment: By "Finding it hard" I mean that strptime on the x['datex'] doesn't work because those are series and not values and I can't apply it to the x in "lambda x" or use %Y%M%d instead of %s.  An example would be date1 = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1) and date2 = datetime.datetime(2014,1,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Finding it hard to strip just the date out since I am working with two columns rather than two values

Well, since you're already using `apply`, you're dealing with two values (not columns), so you can call the `date` method on each:

```
Data.apply(
    lambda x: '%s - %s' % ( xdate1.date() , x.date2.date() ),
    axis=1)
```

The `x` passed to your lambda function is a single row of your dataframe, so accessing `x.date1` (or `x['date1']`) gives a single value of type `Timestamp`. It's easy to extract just the date from that.

Comment: Slick.  Didn't know about the .date() function yet so this will likely help me quite a bit going forward.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

Data = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2014,1,1),
                      datetime(2014,1,3)]],
                      columns=['date1','date2'])

# 
Data['range'] = Data.apply(lambda x:'%s - %s' %
                             (x['date1'].to_pydatetime().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
                              x['date2'].to_pydatetime().strftime("%d/%m/%y")),
                             axis=1)       

print(Data)
```

Result is:

```
       date1      date2
0 2014-01-01 2014-01-03
       date1      date2                  range
0 2014-01-01 2014-01-03  01/01/2014 - 03/01/14
```

Comment: This was good but the other answer was a little bit more concise. Thank you for the help!